# relative imports in the test folder: ImportError

Tags: python, testing, python-import

My Python package layout is usually like this:

```
.
├── setup.py
├── ...
│
├── foobar/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main.py
│   └── ...
│
└── test/
     ├── test_foo.py
     ├── test_bar.py
     ├── helpers.py
     └── ...
```

This works well. Now, when I try to add subfolders in `test/`,

```
.
└── test/
     ├── test_foo/
     │   └── test_feat0.py
     │
     ├── test_bar/
     │   └── test_feat1.py
     │
     └── helpers.py
```

I'm in trouble: The tests in `test_feat0.py` and `test_feat1.py` require something from `helpers.py`, but I cannot

```
from .. import helpers
```

because

```
E   ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I could of course just maintain two copies of `helpers.py` in `test_foo/` and `test_bar/` and `import helpers`, or go back to a flat structure, but that's not desirable.

How else can I work around relative imports in the test folder?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a nicer solution, but you can add this to each of your `test_feat*.py`s:

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

import helpers
```